# How can I specify attribute levels in a mixed logit model?

Tags: attributes, stata, mlogit

I am conducting a study on consumer preferences, where respondents were asked to select a product based on a set of attributes. After running a mixed logit model, I obtained the results below. I am seeking assistance on how to segregate the results by attribute level.

```
. mixlogit y price3, rand(texture ingrid) group(option_set) id(numeric_id) nrep(200) 

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -689.71115  (not concave)
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -685.58262  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -683.87879  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -683.84319  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -683.84307  
Iteration 5:   log likelihood = -683.84307  

Mixed logit model                                       Number of obs =  3,096
                                                    LR chi2(2)    =  11.55
Log likelihood = -683.84307                             Prob > chi2   = 0.0031

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       y | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Mean         |
  price3 |  -.0009266   .0001381    -6.71   0.000    -.0011973   -.0006558
 texture |  -1.174523   .0879522   -13.35   0.000    -1.346906    -1.00214
  ingrid |  -.1090069   .0652664    -1.67   0.095    -.2369268    .0189129
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
SD           |
 texture |   .6666297    .130163     5.12   0.000      .411515    .9217444
  ingrid |   .0030574   .1314769     0.02   0.981    -.2546326    .2607474
------------------------------------------------------------------------------`
```

I attempted to use the `i.` operator, which typically works in multinomial logit analysis. However, I encountered an error indicating that I was performing a time series operation that is not permitted.

```
. mixlogit y price3, rand(i.texture i.ingrid) group(option_set) 
id(numeric_id) 
nrep(200) 
factor-variable and time-series operators not allowed
(error in option rand())
```

I tried to convert the attributes into dummy variables, but the model ended up dropping a majority of the variables due to collinearity.

I would like the results to resemble those presented below. Instead of using a conditional logit model, a mixed logit model should be employed.

```
. clogit y price3 i.texture5 i.ingrid5, group(numeric_id) 
note: 5.ingrid5 omitted because of collinearity.
note: multiple positive outcomes within groups encountered.

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -2132.9689  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -2132.5788  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -2132.5786  

Conditional (fixed-effects) logistic regression        Number of obs =   9,288
                                                       LR chi2(6)    = 1402.42
                                                       Prob > chi2   =  0.0000
Log likelihood = -2132.5786                            Pseudo R2     =  0.2474

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      price3 |  -.0016488   .0001815    -9.09   0.000    -.0020044   -.0012931
             |
    texture5 |
     coarse  |   1.692396   .6769401     2.50   0.012     .3656177    3.019174
       fine  |   2.705765   .6652764     4.07   0.000     1.401847    4.009683
             |
     ingrid5 |
 70,20,0,10  |   .9481876   .1057004     8.97   0.000     .7410186    1.155357
  100,0,0,0  |  -1.167767   .1452245    -8.04   0.000    -1.452401 -.8831319
 70,15,10,5  |   .5271418   .1093191     4.82   0.000     .3128803    .7414032
  Other  |          0  (omitted)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please show us the commands that **didn't** work.  The problem is quite possibly a trivial typo, but it is hard to debug code you don't show us.

Comment: Strictly `i.` is not a command.  It is an operator.

Comment: Stata dropping variables (meaning, omitting them from a model) is exactly what you would expect given multicollinearity. It raises (statistical and in this instance possibly economic) questions abiut your model specification, but it is not a programming problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have incorporated your comments into the edited version of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. Stata doesn't support specification of factor variables to that option.  If that procedure is defined in the literature, it is not yet implemented Otherwise I am not expert on this kind of model and can't tell you whether the request makes sense statistically.